# Reactive Spring Security: @PreAuthorize Spring-EL Expression with Mono

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

Is there any way we can use reactive types in the Spring-EL expression?

Given the following example:

```
    @PreAuthorize("@authz.verify(#members)")
    fun createTopic(members: List<UserId>): Mono<Topic> {

        // ...
    }


    @Service("authz")
    class TopicAuthorizationEvaluator() {   

        fun verify(members: Iterable<UserId>): Mono<Boolean> {

            // returns a Mono<Boolean> !!!
        }
    }
```

The method verify returns a `Mono<Boolean>`

However, when I call the method Spring throws:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E: Type conversion problem, cannot convert from reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallableOnAssembly<java.lang.Boolean> to java.lang.Boolean
```

**UPDATE:**

I found out its an open issue with Spring Security:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4841

Comment: Custom permission evaluators must be return a boolean

Comment: Yes, correct :(